# Prepend value to switchMap with Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, reactive

Every time `this.selectedLanguage$` emits a new value I need to emit a value calculated asynchronously.
The code I came up with is the following:

```
public readonly languageCategories$ = this.selectedLanguage$.pipe(
  switchMap(x => this._matchService.getCategoriesAsync(x)),
  shareReplay());
```

I used `switchMap` because if the `selectedLanguage` changes while obtaining the categories, the async call should be discarded and a new one started.

The problem is that every time the async method starts being awaited I want `languageCategories` to emit `null` (which means categories are being calculated, `[]` would be misleading).
How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What's the purpose of the `null` being emitted ? Are you just looking for a way to know when a new value is being calculated ?

Comment: exactly, the `null` invalidates the previous value while the new one is being calculated, and should not be `[]` cause it would have a wrong meaning, as a side effect (which is needed) it can be used as a loading indicator

Answer (score 0):

Here would be an approach:

```js
languageCategories$ = this.selectedLanguage$.pipe(
  switchMap(
    x => merge(
      of(null), // Emit `null` right away - start loading
      this._matchService.getCategoriesAsync(x),
    )
  ),

  // shareReplay() ? not sure about this
);
```

I commented `shareReplay` because I'm not sure it should be there, because it will also cache the `null` values(emitted when the async op start *loading*). In order to avoid this, you could try this:

```js
languageCategories$ = this.selectedLanguage$.pipe(
  switchMap(
    x => merge(
      of(null),
      this._matchService.getCategoriesAsync(x),
    )
  ),
  tap(v => v === null && doSideEffect()),
  filter(v => !!v),
  shareReplay()
);
```

Also, beware that you can add some configurations to the `shareReplay` operator: `shareReplay({ bufferSize, windowTime, scheduler, refCount })`, where

- `bufferSize` - **how many** values should be cached; if the limit is exceeded, the oldest stored value will be disposed
- `windowTime` - **how long** the values should be stored
- `scheduler` - specify a custom scheduler
- `refCount` - if the `ReplaySubject`(that is used behind the scenes) should be destroyed if there are no active subscribers